# Determining the next Twin Prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, twin-primes

A really simple I question I guess. Is there an algorithm or method such that given an integer $N$ there is a way to determine the next twin prime pair greater than $N$?

If yes, then could you please explain it?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask if there exists an efficient algorithm for finding twin primes.  Otherwise, a brute force search could be implemented.

Comment: well basically something other than a brute force

Comment: There are established and extremely fast ways of finding primes. There just aren't any theoretically faster ways to find twin primes. In practice, you could improve an algorithm by a constant factor if you only searched for those. If you wanted just one prime, you might as well use brute force. Unless you wanted it extremely quickly, in which case you could use a divide and conquer approach that 'guesses' where the prime might be.

Comment: If you use simple trial division, at least you can reject numbers that are not twin primes quicker: To check whether p is prime, you would check that it is odd and not divisible by 3, 5, 7 etc. up to sqrt (p). To check whether p and p+2 are twin primes, you check they are odd, then you check whether (p+2) modulo x <= 2 and then (p+2) modulo x != 1, for x = 3, 5, 7 etc. So a pair will be rejected if a factor for one is found. Which will happen earlier on average than finding a factor of one number only. Only _actual_ twin primes will not be examined faster.

Answer (score 18):

It isn't even known that there is always a twin prime pair greater than $N$ (so strictly speaking, there isn't an algorithm that is known to work).

Comment: Thats interesting, so if an algorithm is devised that works and it doesn't involve some extension of determine if P and P + 2 is prime then that would be considered an adequate proof of the twin prime conjecture?

Comment: There exists an algorithm. For there are two possibilities, (i) infinitely many twins or (ii) not. In case (i), there is an obvious algorithm. In case (ii), if we input a number $N$ that is too big, it says "You are SOL." We just don't happen to know which is the right algorithm.

Comment: I'm going to be logging out real soon but my question comes down to this: if I have an algorithm right now that always converges,

Comment: *it didn't let me hit enter, anyways if I have an algorithm that is guaranteed to converge, never checks primes numbers greater than N, and so far has always converged to the correct twin prime pair greater than N it might be worth sharing w/others?

Comment: In a practical sense, any algorithm to find prime numbers finds twin primes. While it isn't known in a mathematical, theoretic sense whether there is an infinite amount of prime numbers, this directly implies that with current technology, it is not feasible to construct a machine that will not find twin primes.

Comment: "It is not feasible to construct a machine that will not find twin primes?"  I'm pretty sure my toaster is a machine that will not find twin primes.

Comment: Oh darn it you're right. I was so wrong in saying that. A toaster! Of course. I should have thought of that. I retract my statement.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas depends on how quickly it converges, and what you can prove about the algorithm's correctness.

Answer (score 7):

Let $x=N+1$.  If $x$ and $x+2$ are prime, you're done.  If not, let $x=x+1$ and repeat.  :-P

Comment: Hmm... thats clever, but not exactly what i was thinking

Comment: lol, I didn't really think it was clever, but yeah what @Robert said.  One of the great unsolved problems of math right now is the infinitude of twin primes...

Comment: This works, but 10 minutes after you posted this answer, the OP commented that he desired something other than brute force. If there happen to be finitely many prime pairs, for a large enough $N$, this algorithm would behave like a calculator that was not built with the knowledge that division by $0$ is illegal.

Comment: Even better: if $N$ is even, let $x=N+1$, else $x=N+2$ and then always increment $x$ by 2 and keep primality test of the previous one. You can also keep track of multiple of three because at least one between x, x+2 and x+3 is a multiple of three...

Comment: Let $x = x+2$ if $x$ isn't prime or $x = x+4$, prime can't be even ($x \neq 2$), and we checked $x+2$. ;) Here helpful could be [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Answer (score 4):

Nope. As far as I know there's no algorithm beyond sieveing for primes past $N$ until you find a twin pair.

Comment: Thats intriguing that nobody has found one yet...

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$\sigma_0(n−1) + \sigma_0(n+1)−4 \ge 0$$
with equality exactly when $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes, what about a generating function like
\begin{align}
 \frac{4}{x-1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}(x^2\!+1)}{1-x^k}
 &= - 3 - 2x - x^2\! + x^3\! + 3x^5\! + 4x^7\! + x^8\! + 4x^{9}\! + x^{10}\! \\
  &\hspace{3em} + 6x^{11}\! + 6x^{13}\! + 2x^{14}\! + 5x^{15}\! + 2x^{16}\! + 7x^{17}\! + 8x^{19}\! + \cdots,
\end{align}
where the set of missing exponents, $\{4,6,12,18,30,42,\dots\}$, is the set of twin prime separators? Does that suit your needs?

Comment: Wait... hold up... how do we derive this?

Comment: The LHS is seriously miscomposed: summing over $n$ a quantity not depending on $n$?

Comment: If you sum over $x$, the sum should not involve $x$...

Comment: Including $x=1$?

Comment: I am clearly not notating it correctly. (I have very little experience with Taylor series, obviously.) Could someone please tell me how to correctly notate it? When I put

taylor (4/(x-1)+sum(x^(k-1)*(x^2+1)/(1-x^k),k,1,infty),x,0,N)

into maxima (where $N$ is an arbitrary positive integer), I get the series on the right-hand side of the equation in my answer.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I would have thought it was self-evident how to derive the function itself, even if it’s not possible to prove that the function has an infinite number of zeros…? If the derivation isn’t self-evident, then I should probably keep working on the second part of the puzzle.  =)

Comment: The formula was again nonsensical, I tried to keep only the relevant parts. Now, what we are missing is an explanation of why you think that the expansion of the LHS as a power series omits exactly the powers in the set of twin prime separators. (Interestingly, the OP found this answer useful as soon as it was posted, in its first form, 18 months ago.)

Comment: @Did: $$\sigma_0(n-1)+\sigma_0(n+1)-4 \ge 0$$ with equality exactly when $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both primes. Correct?

Comment: Suggestion (bis): Add this to the answer.

Comment: @Did: Done. Thanks for the suggestion, and the help with the notation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss timidpueo's “algorithm” (although it could easily be made faster by replacing $N+1$ by $N+6$, among other tricks).  Conjecturally, the average spacing between twin primes is $O(\log^2 N)$ and the worst-case spacing is $O(\log^3 N)$.  So in practice, this is a polynomial time “algorithm” (even though it is not guaranteed to terminate, hence the quotes).

Comment: If the requirement is to find the next twin prime, though, you cannot rely on probabilistic algorithms. Though you could use this in order to increase the efficiency of the algorithm by employing a divide and conquer approach.

Comment: *Can all the prime numbers less than a number N be determined in polynomial time?

Comment: Oh definitely. Look up the various sieves.

Comment: Polynomial in $N$, yes, but "polynomial time" usually means polynomial in the size of the input (thus polynomial in $\log(N)$), and there are too many primes for that.

Comment: ahhh so it still is a slow process to find them

Comment: No? It is only a slow process in a theoretical sense. In a practical sense it is not.

Comment: "the worst-case spacing is $O(\log^3 N)$"... this seems to imply that there are an infinite number of twin primes.

Comment: @robjohn That was intended to fall under the "Conjecturally" clause.

Answer (score 1):

There's a superfast method:
Don't look for primes! Look for one tiny class of semiprimes. The product of all twin primes is an even perfect square minus 1. And since we're searching for semiprimes, a primality test is not required. Any factor (prime or not) less than the square root of X^2 - 1 eliminates the composite as a candidate. Furthermore, these factors are usually trivial - that is, they're found long before X.

Demonstration: http://www.naturalnumbers.org/TwinPrimeCalc.xlsm